# Couldn't find matching GLX visual (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, games

When I execute etracer (ExtremeTuxRacer) from within a terminal all I get is:

"etracer error: Couldn't initialize video: Couldn't find matching GLX visual (Resource temporarily unavailable)"

I have an Intel graphics adapter that runs compiz and other 3d games just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted ~/.etracer and it fixed itself...